# Montar repositorio restic alojado en Azure

Tags: azure-storage

En mi empresa tenemos un antiguo repositorio de Restic en un Blob Container pero no sabemos que hay dentro del repositorio.
Como podríamos montarlo para poder ver el contenido?

En la documentación he encontrado como crear un repositorio y alojarlo en azure, pero no como puedo hacer para importarlo.

Creemos que no hay nada importante pero tenemos que asegurarnos antes de borrarlo definitivamente

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Algo como [esto](https://restic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/050_restore.html)?